# Why does the react-admin menu bar not redirect me to the correct resource view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, menu, react-admin

I have created a sandbox for this problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-menu-problem-s4jfl?file=/src/Admin.js
when you click enter https://s4jfl.csb.app/#/AdminPanel into the search bar, and click on the `users` resource, it returns the error.

I am creating an admin panel for my react app using react-admin. Everything was working perfectly fine until yesterday. I didn't use a Custom AppBar nor Provider. When I click on the menu, the URL in the web-browser changes but the page does not redirect. My app is not large so I didn't use react-redux.

For example, when I click on `Categories` from my dashboard, the URL changes from `http://localhost:3000/AdminPanel/` to `http://localhost:3000/AdminPanel/#/Categories`, and the console sends a warning:

```
Uncaught Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"
```

Though the URL changes, the contents of the page still stay at the `dashboard`. But when I click on the URL and press enter, the page refreshes and contents are correct.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Admin.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource } from "react-admin";
import {
  FirebaseDataProvider,
  FirebaseAuthProvider,
} from "react-admin-firebase";

import {
  CategoryList,
  CategoryCreate,
  CategoryEdit,
  CategoryShow,
} from "./Pages/categories";
import {
  ProductList,
  ProductCreate,
  ProductEdit,
  ProductShow,
} from "./Pages/products";
import {
  OptionsList,
  OptionEdit,
  OptionCreate,
  OptionShow,
} from "./Pages/options";
import { ResponseList, ResponseShow } from "./Pages/responses";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard";
import CustomLoginPage from "./Login/CustomLoginPage";
import Category from "@material-ui/icons/Category";
import ShoppingCart from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCart";
import LibraryBooks from "@material-ui/icons/LibraryBooks";
import QuestionAnswerIcon from "@material-ui/icons/QuestionAnswer";

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "00000000000",
  appId: "1:123456789:web:qiwehw9e8jafiuqdeqiqn",
  measurementId: "X-XXXXXXXX",
};

const options = {};

const dataProvider = FirebaseDataProvider(config, options);
const authProvider = FirebaseAuthProvider(config, options);

const AdminPanel = () => (
  <Admin
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    loginPage={CustomLoginPage}
  >
    <Resource
      name="Category"
      list={CategoryList}
      edit={CategoryEdit}
      create={CategoryCreate}
      show={CategoryShow}
      icon={Category}
    />
    <Resource
      name="Options"
      list={OptionsList}
      edit={OptionEdit}
      create={OptionCreate}
      show={OptionShow}
      icon={LibraryBooks}
    />
    <Resource
      name="Products"
      list={ProductList}
      edit={ProductEdit}
      create={ProductCreate}
      show={ProductShow}
      icon={ShoppingCart}
    />
    <Resource
      name="Responses"
      list={ResponseList}
      show={ResponseShow}
      icon={QuestionAnswerIcon}
    />
  </Admin>
);

export default AdminPanel;
```

**CustomLoginPage**

```
import React from "react";
import { Login, LoginForm } from "react-admin";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";
import firebase from "firebase";
import ForgotPasswordButton from "./CustomForgotPassword";

const uiConfig = {
  signInFlow: "popup",
  signInSuccessUrl: "#/",
  signInOptions: [],
};

const SignInScreen = () => (
  <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
);

const CustomLoginForm = (props) => (
  <div>
    <LoginForm {...props} />
    <ForgotPasswordButton {...props} />
    <SignInScreen />
  </div>
);

const CustomLoginPage = (props) => (
  <Login {...props}>
    <CustomLoginForm {...props} />
  </Login>
);

export default CustomLoginPage;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import AdminPanel from "./Admin/Admin";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router basename="/">
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/AdminPanel" component={AdminPanel} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "./",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.10.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.0.2",
    ...
    "firebase": "^7.15.2",
    ...
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-admin": "^3.7.1",
    "react-admin-firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
    ...
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    ...
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "https://asia-east2-xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/api"
}
```

**Edited:**
An example:
When I click on the menu to `category` this is what I see:
[image]
And this is what I expect to see:
[image]
Thanks

Included Code for Categories:
This is not just happening for categories, but for all the resource pages. According to what I know, react-admin will automatically help me link all my resource pages to the menu so the user will be redirected upon click, which is also the case for me before this happened. Since I didn't create a custom menu (AppBar) and just used the default menu, everything should be working fine, however, it seems like there is something going on with the menu which only changes the url (on the web browser) but does not re-render the application(admin panel) for the user?
**Categories.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  EditButton,
  Create,
  TextInput,
  SimpleForm,
  Edit,
  Filter,
  ShowButton,
  DeleteButton,
  SimpleShowLayout,
  DateField,
  Show,
  RichTextField,
  NumberInput,
  NumberField,
} from "react-admin";

const CategoryTitle = ({ record }) => {
  return <span>Category {record ? `"${record.name}"` : ""}</span>;
};

const CategoryFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="name" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);

export const CategoryList = (props) => (
  <List
    filters={<CategoryFilter />}
    {...props}
    title="Categories(Questions) for the Quiz"
    sort={{ field: "index", order: "ASC" }}
  >
    <Datagrid>
      {/* <TextField source="index" /> */}
      <TextField source="name" />
      {/* <TextField source="id" /> */}
      <RichTextField label="Description" multiline="true" source="body" />
      <NumberField source="index" />
      <ShowButton />
      <EditButton />
      <DeleteButton redirect={false} />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);

export const CategoryShow = (props) => (
  <Show title={<CategoryTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleShowLayout {...props}>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="name" />
      <RichTextField label="Description" multiline="true" source="body" />
      <NumberField source="index" />
      <DateField source="lastupdate" showTime />
      <TextField source="updatedby" />
    </SimpleShowLayout>
  </Show>
);
export const CategoryEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit title={<CategoryTitle />} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput disabled source="id" />
      {/* <TextInput disabled source="index" /> */}
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput label="Description" source="body" />
      <NumberInput source="index" step={1} min="1" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);

export const CategoryCreate = (props) => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      {/* <TextInput source="index" /> */}
      <TextInput source="name" />
      <TextInput label="Description" source="body" />
      <NumberInput source="index" step={1} min="1" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```

Comment: Idk might be I have a bad vision but I did not see anything for `/#/Categories`.
Can you point me how and what you wish to be rendered while doing `/AdminPanel/#/Categories`

Comment: @PrabeshGouli Thanks for your help, I have included some screenshots, see if you understand now.

Comment: please include code of `./pages/categories/` in question, To jump on categories you must make route up to categories.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli please check. I believe that I do not have to custom the routes since react-admin does that for me?